# Unable to retrive data from xml format

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xcode

I need to retrive data from a given xml Format. How can I retrieve the data? [Here is a link to the XML](http://vowelsgroup.com/ItTutorialsBank/tutorials.xml).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add the delegate for URLConnection and pasrsing in your header file:

Delegate to add is:

1. `NSURLConnectionDelegate`
2. `NSXMLParserDelegate`

then you have to call the XML URL:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods which will be like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError = %@",[error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");

    xmlParser= [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:responseData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
}
```

Then add the xmlParser delegate methods:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
//The tags in the xml data, the opening tags
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString*)string {
//The data in tags
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didEndElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qName {
//The end of each tags
}
```

Here is a good tutorial for dealing with XML data: [Tutorial](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html)

Comment: am gettng response the problem is when am parsing with xml parser delegates i am getting problem

Comment: parser didStartElement                                    currentElement = [elementName copy];
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"MainMenu"])
           { item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                sub = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                subsub = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
               sub1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
              }

Comment: What is the problem you have here, everything look correct.